# Update field in double nested arrays with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Another problem working with mongoose. I want to update `task` in document as example below. 
For example I want to update `completed` field in task with `_id=1` in `project` with `name` inbox.
Is it possible to do in one query?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5702e0c732faf57c7bb9ebe9"),
    "email" : "john@doe.me",
    "projects" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "1",
            "name" : "inbox",
            "tasks" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "1",
                    "text" : "First task",
                    "labels" : [ 
                        "home", 
                        "phone"
                    ],
                    "dueDate" : "2016-03-18T11:10:00",
                    "created" : "2016-03-10T10:10:00",
                    "completed" : true
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "2",
                    "text" : "Second task",
                    "labels" : [ 
                        "home", 
                        "phone"
                    ],
                    "dueDate" : "2016-03-18T11:10:00",
                    "created" : "2016-03-10T10:10:00",
                    "completed" : false
                }, 
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "2",
            "name" : "work",
            "tasks" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "4",
                    "text" : "Fourth",
                    "labels" : [ 
                        "home", 
                        "phone"
                    ],
                    "dueDate" : "2016-03-18T11:10:00",
                    "created" : "2016-03-10T10:10:00",
                    "completed" : false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mongo, it is not possible to query and update nested arrays at once. The positional `$` operator, that would be needed here, does not support traversing nested arrays.

From [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays):

> The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value

See [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) for more information.

Comment: finally I did what I need inside callback using forEach to look up nested arrays element and updating it

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible. You need to use positional operator. Please try this:

```
db.yourCollection.update({
        "_id" : ObjectId("5702e0c732faf57c7bb9ebe9"),
        'projects.tasks._id': '1'
      },
      { $set: { 'projects.tasks.$.completed': newData }}
    )
```

Comment: I've tried this

  User.update(
          {_id: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId), 'projects.tasks._id': Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data.task._id) },
          { $set: { 'projects.tasks.$.completed': data.task.completed }},
          (err, data) => {
            console.log(data);
            return reply('success');
          }
        );

but in return I got { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }

Comment: Many reasons might be happened. Not quite sure. I suggest that you should try this in your mongoshell first (find _id s properly or try another fields instead of _id). Also you can add another property into first paramater on update. Like 'projects._id': '1'.

Comment: Or the problem might be your field type. If your 'completed' is Boolean and you send String field, mongo does not allow to modify that field. As I said, you have to try on your mongo shell first.

Comment: This will not work at all. The positional operator doesn't work with multiply nested arrays, as described in panjan's answer.